# Can we connect AWS secret Manager directly from frontend application like React?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

It might be a very basic question to ask .But as I am very naive to AWS now and has been basically a frontend developer I would like to have some guidance related to fetching secrets from AWS secret manager from a react application.

1. Can we connect frontend React application directly to AWS secret manager or we should have a node application in the middle to fetch secret from AWS secret manger?
   2.If we can connect front end application directly to AWS is there any tutorial or steps that I can follow?

Comment: Questions that don't mention any code are not typically a good fit for Stack Overflow

Comment: Yes, but you need credentials to do that and you don't want credentials statically in your web page. So you need to get credentials dynamically. You can do that with a server (e.g. Node.js) or you may want to consider AWS Amplify.

Comment: @jarmod thanks for the suggestion .It helps.

Comment: @JuanMendes this is in a very priliminary stage of my project and I am trying to gather understanding about the feasibility and how to achieve this before coding and hence the question does not have any code in it.

Comment: That's why it's not a good fit :)

Comment: @PayelDutta, how did you use secret manager in your react client? I am having the same requirement.